# What type of data that stored in sensor after converting an audio signal into digital (ADC)

Tags: c, matlab, audio, sensors

Please excuse my lack of knowledge but I tried to search for an answer for couple days and I wasn't able to figure this out.

I'm trying to do a simulation for acoustic sensor (mica2) that sense audio signal and do some feature extraction, etc.
In matlab, when I read an audio file (ex. using readaudio) it will give me a normalised values between -1 and 1 that represents that amplitude of the signal and then i do the feature extraction using these values.

However, now I'm trying to simulate the sensor using Avrora and using C implementation, so, I represented the sample values as float numbers but I'm not sure if that is correct.

So, basically, my questions are:

- How sensors store the signal after A/D conversion? I mean the digital signal sample values (an array of float or integer numbers?) and are they represent the amplitude of the signal?
- Can I do the feature extraction directly on the digital signal?
- I assumed that I have an array of size 4000 (because sensors has 4kb RAM) that stored a float numbers that represent the signal samples. Is that correct?

Comment: Not float!  Hardware really does not like floats.

Comment: So are they an integer values that represent the signal amplitude?

Comment: ADC generally: The signal voltage in its specified range is converted to a number within the specified digital range. If there are 12 bits in the result, the resolution gives 4096 discrete values from the infinity of input voltages. You can convert these to a floating point representation of the signal range, bearing in mind that the digital value may be unsigned even if the input voltage can be negative, depending on circuitry and configuration. Or you can normalise them to the range -1 to +1. My understanding of "amplitude" is the general range of values. A single sample is just its level.

Comment: Thank you very much, so basically the values that i'll get after the ADC is an integer values ? so basically when i represent them in the simulation i'll represent it as an array of type int10 ?

Comment: I do not know the device you are using or its capabilities. My comment was a general remark about ADC devices.

Comment: Beware that while every 12 bit ADC has 4096 possible values, some ADCs space them linearly and some space them... differently.  Have a look at [mu-law PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm), for an example.

Answer (score 1):

read up on [PCM - pulse code modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) which is the fundamental raw audio format ... basically audio is just a curve typically varying from -1 to +1 with silence as a zero signal ... this digital signal must get stored into 8 bit bytes ... greater audio fidelity means greater number of bytes per point on this audio curve ... one byte ( 8 bits ) by definition offers only 2^8 distinct values == 256 different values to get spread from -1 to +1 ... CD quality audio uses two bytes ( 16 bit ) which gives you 2^16 different values spread from -1 to +1 ... 24 bit and 32 bit audio exist yet same benefits there ... so yes your digital audio curve is represented by integers (16 bit signed ints, or unsigned ints if you shift your data from -1 to +1 to a spread of 0 to +1)

feature extraction :  well you are dealing with a time series curve however there is an entire subfield when human perception is involved ... too much there for a short SO question

what is Avrora ?  are you spelling it correctly ?

you mention 4k of memory ... do the math :   44.1khz sample rate  this gives you just a fraction of a second of audio so that buffer is populated then immediately transferred down the wire in preparation for next set of samples ... a point on the audio curve is one sample ... quality is determined by two factors :  (1) how many samples per second ( sample rate ) typically 44.1khz and (2) resolution (number of storage bits) allocated to store the audio curve height (bit depth) typically 16 bits ...

any sensor simply generates a series of sample measurements of the audio curve ... each sample represents the height of the audio curve as it varies from say -1 to +1 ... typically a new sample is performed 44,100 times per second ... so for one second of recording you have 44,100 numbers ... each sample is a single measurement which outputs a single number typically integers the range of integers is determined by sensor bit depth ...

if the curve varies from -1 to +1 so will your sample values ... to represent this in digital format we must understand the notion of storage capacity of bits ... lets say we have a one bit sensor (not your 10 bit sensor) ... a one bit sensor by definition can only output two distinct values :  0 or 1 why only two values ? because one bit has 2^1 possible values available  ... a two bit sensor can give you 4 distinct values : 0 1 2 3 because 2^2 == 4 ... a 3 bit sensor offers 8 distinct values since 2^3 is 8 ... now you have a 10 bit sensor then it can output 2^10 distinct values ... remember what is getting measured here :  height of the audio curve ...

if we have a 10 bit sensor a given sample measurement will be one of 2^10 distinct possible values, since 2^10 == 1024 so possible sample values would range from 0, 1,2 ... up to 1023 [ from 0 to (2^n - 1)] ...

For simplicity lets stick to unsigned integers ( all positive from 0 on up) ... if your audio curve samples vary from -1 to +1 then to represent that range as unsigned integers just add 1 to the sample and divide by 2 ... (SAMPLE + 1)/2 which will output values from 0 to +1 instead of -1 to +1 ...

To quote your comment :  "if my sensor use 10 bit ADC, i will get a vector of values between -1 and 1, and i'll get different 1024 values?"

Answer : possibly but not likely ... it depends on the input audio signal ... one sample will generate one integer in a range of possible values from 0 to 1023 ... to output 1024 different values this would require 1024 samples each with a different value meaning the audio curve change in height would have to vary in lock step with each new sample and the audio curve would have to vary across its entire range of -1 to +1, or 0 to +1 (what the range actually is can be ignored since its always normalized to an easy to use range -1 to +1 or 0 to +1, or whatever you like)

Even though you have a 10 bit sensor, it is likely stored using two bytes (consuming 16 bits) which makes the code simpler yet less efficient use of storage.  It is possible to store 10 bit data into a 4,000 byte buffer giving you 400 samples however that would be computationally slower using more complex code logic.  So if it does use two bytes (16 bits) of storage for each 10 bit sample, your 4000 byte buffer would hold 2000 samples of single channel audio

Comment: Thank you very much, highly appreciate it. Yes Avrora is a simulator for mica2 sensor, that allow me to measure the cycles, energy consumption, and time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm new in audio field, so could you kindly explain this more to me, so basically if my sensor use 10 bit ADC, i will get a vector of values between -1 and 1, and i'll get different 1024 values? and i thought that because i have 4kb RAM that means in each time the sensor will process a block of samples (4000 samples), so that i assumed i have an array of size 4000. Thank you again for taking from your time to replay me